# Extracting attributes that are in XML tags with BeautifulSoup4

Tags: python, xml, beautifulsoup, tags

Sample input:

```
<subj code1="textA" code2="textB" code3="textC">
    <txt count="1">
        <txt id="123">
            This is my text.
        </txt>
    </txt>
</subj>
```

I am experimenting with BeautifulSoup to extract information from an XML into a CSV.
My desired output is

```
code1,code2,code3,txt
textA,textB,textC,This is my text.
```

I have been playing with this sample code, which I found [here](https://gist.github.com/matthewbelisle-wf/4171684):
It works in regards to extracting `txt` but not in code1,code2,code3 in the tag `subj`.

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    with open('sample.csv', 'w') as fhandle:
        writer = csv.writer(fhandle)
        writer.writerow(('code1', 'code2', 'code3', 'text'))
        for subj in soup.find_all('subj'):
            for x in subj:
                writer.writerow((subj.code1.text,
                                subj.code2.text,
                                subj.code3.text,
                                subj.txt.txt))
```

but, I cannot get it to recognize also the attributes in `subj` that I want to extract.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`code1`, `code2` and `code3` are not texts, they are *attributes*.

In order to access them, [treat an element as a dictionary](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#attributes):

```
(subj['code1'], subj['code2'], subj['code3'], subj.get_text(strip=True)))
```

Demo:

```
In [1]: from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

In [2]: data = """
   ...: <subj code1="textA" code2="textB" code3="textC">
   ...:     <txt count="1">
   ...:         <txt id="123">
   ...:             This is my text.
   ...:         </txt>
   ...:     </txt>
   ...: </subj>
   ...: """

In [3]: soup = BeautifulSoup(data, "xml")
In [4]: for subj in soup('subj'):
    ...:     print([subj['code1'], subj['code2'], subj['code3'], subj.get_text(strip=True)])  
['textA', 'textB', 'textC', 'This is my text.']
```

You can also use `.get()` to provide a default value if an attribute is missing:

```
subj.get('code1', 'Default value for code1')
```